# One server, 2 sites, 1 cached with varnish, the other one can't delete session

Tags: python, wordpress, flask, varnish

The scenario is the following:
1x EC2 micro-instance that hosts 2 sites, 1 wordpress blog and 1 flask-powered site, say: wpsite.com & flasksite.com.
Both are served with nginx that listens on 8080, then varnish listening on 80 acts as proxy for nginx. **I have to cache only wpsite.com and I'd want to skip the cache engine for flasksite.com**.

This is the VCL:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

sub vcl_recv {
   if (!req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?wpsite\.com$") {
        return(pass);
   }

   remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
   set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

   if (req.request == "PURGE") {
     if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
       error 405 "Not allowed.";
     }
     return(lookup);
   }
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    #revisit this list
    if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png|gz|tgz|bz2)(\?.*|)$") {
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
  }
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
  }
  if (req.url ~ "\?(utm_(campaign|medium|source|term)|adParams|client|cx|eid|fbid|feed|ref(id|src)?|v(er|iew))=") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
  }
  if (req.http.cookie) {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "(wordpress_|wp-settings-)") {
      return(pass);
    } else {
      unset req.http.cookie;
    }
  }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.url ~ "manager" || req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php") {
    return (hit_for_pass);
  }
  if ( (!(req.url ~ "manager" ||  req.url ~ "(wp-(login|admin)|login)")) || (req.request == "GET") ) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
   set beresp.ttl = 1h;
  }
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 365d;
  }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
   if (obj.hits > 0) {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
   } else {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
   }
}
sub vcl_hit {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    set obj.ttl = 0s;
    error 200 "OK";
  }
}

sub vcl_miss {
  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    error 404 "Not cached";
  }
}
```

The issue:
all seems to works good but:
I've a login system in flasksite.com that relies on cookie-session: if I do the login the system works but if I want to do logout the cookie remains there.

These are the views of flasksite.com for login/logout:

```
@bp.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    if 'username' in session:
        del session['username']
    return redirect(url_for('.start'))

@bp.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if 'username' not in session:
        db_user = database.get_user(request.form['username'])
        if db_user:
            if check_password(db_user['password'], request.form['password']):
                session['username'] = request.form['username']
                if 'remember_flag' in request.form:
                    session.permanent = True
                else:
                    session.permanent = False
            else:
                pass # wrong password
        else:
            pass # user not in db
    return redirect(url_for('.start'))
```

If I drop varnish between nginx & clients all works like a charm.
Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved adding the following in vcl_fetch:

```
  if (!req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?wpsite\.com$") {
     return (hit_for_pass);
  }
```